# using annotation with OpenMath in MathML and MathJax

Tags: xml, html, mathjax, mathml

I'm trying to use OpenMath in MathML by MathJax. The code is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mixed Markup</title>

    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
        MathJax.Hub.Config({
            MathML: {
                extensions: ["content-mathml.js"]
            }
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" async
            src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
        <semantics>
            <mrow>
                <mrow>
                    <mi>sin</mi>
                    <mo>&#x2061;<!--FUNCTION APPLICATION--></mo>
                    <mfenced><mi>x</mi></mfenced>
                </mrow>
                <mo>+</mo>
                <mn>5</mn>
            </mrow>
            <annotation encoding="application/x-tex">
                \sin x + 5
            </annotation>
            <annotation-xml encoding="application/openmath+xml">
                <OMA xmlns="http://www.openmath.org/OpenMath">
                    <OMS cd="arith1" name="plus"/>
                    <OMA><OMS cd="transc1" name="sin"/><OMV name="x"/></OMA>
                    <OMI>5</OMI>
                </OMA>
            </annotation-xml>
        </semantics>
    </math>    
</body>
```

When I wrote above code, the content of annotation-xal tag and OMA are
colored red like captured image following

[image]

(for more detail, 
the reason of red line on `encoding` is `Wrong attribute value`
and on `xmlns` is `URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)`

And in the document of MathML3 (http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML3/chapter5.html#html.annotation.xml), they said

"Note that the Namespace extensibility used in the examples may not be available if the MathML is not being treated as an XML document. ... In particular HTML parsers treat xmlns attributes as ordinary attributes, so the OpenMath example would be clasified as invalid by an HTML validator."

But I don't understand the meaning of it, expecially 'MathML is not being treated as an XML document'

What can I do to use OpenMath(?) in MathML and MathJax ?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintainer of the W3C HTML checker (validator) here. I don’t know what tool produced the output in the question, but I’m guessing the reason those parts are in red are just because the HTML checker reports errors for those parts.

For MathML, I guess the checker’s a bit more strict than needed. In particular, it doesn’t recognize OpenMath at all, because some years ago I [yanked all OpenMath-specific code from the checker](https://github.com/validator/validator/commit/b99ef0) at the request of somebody from the MathML working group.

However, that doesn’t mean your code won’t work correctly in MathJax. If it works as expected in MathJax then you can safely ignore the messages from whatever tool is reporting those errors.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness !! Can you give an address or anything for 'MathML integration'?? I want to see it for studying :)

Comment: Well for example, the reason the checker reports an error for `<annotation-xml encoding="application/openmath+xml">` is because of [lines 84-86 in a RelaxNG schema file](https://github.com/validator/validator/blob/master/schema/mml3/mathml3-common.rnc#L84) the checker uses to determined what the allowed values are. Those lines restrict it to the values `application/xhtml+xml` and `text/html`. It wouldn’t be completely unreasonable to argue that’s too strict, or even wouldn’t be completely unreasonable to argue that we should allow any value at all there for the `encoding` attribute.